# node build: read node_modules included on page and push them in an array bundle

Tags: node.js, build

I have included couple of node modules on my app like:

```
  <script src="../node_modules/a/a.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/b/b.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/c/c.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/d/dist/js/d.js"></script>
```

I want to concat and minify them in a file. But before that I need an array with their names. I don't want to manually add them. How can I automatically read them from my app index file and add them to an array?

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like webpack, rollup, or browserify to transpile, concat and minify all of your modules into one or more bundled files.  I personally use webpack.  There are many tutorials available online.

Comment: I want to use node as my build tool. I have limited resources and want to keep size of the app and number of the node modules that I include as low as possible.

Comment: All of these tools run on top of node.  They are also extendable with plugins.  If you don't use plugins like babel then the dependencies will be much less